# Node-persist : initSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, persist

I have just started learning Nodejs.
And i'm learning about persist module. Here my code:

```
var storage = require('node-persist');
// console.log(storage);
storage.initSync();
```

But i met this error

> TypeError: storage.initSync is not a function

And when console.log storage, it has only create and init

> { create: [Function], init: [Function] }

Does my code wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the 3.0.0 change log

> All the *Sync functions were removed, every operation is now asynchronous

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist#300-change-logs

Answer (score 1):

It changed in V 3.0. but if you want to use in sync way you can say:

```
var storage = require('node-persist');
await storage.initSync();
```